# How to get a link to the user's facebook profile on iOS?

Tags: ios, facebook

I have an iOS app which has an in-app comments section. I'd like to ask a user whether they want to "link" their comment name to their facebook page or not. If a user says yes, then I'd like to grab their facebook profile page's web address and store it, so when other users see this user's comment, they can click to go to that person's facebook profile.

Is there any kind of easy way to do this without implementing the full facebook sdk without going through all the authentications?

I'm not very familiar with the Facebook SDK, so any help is appreciated...

Comment: plz intimate correctly Facebook Pages are separate and profile page is separate

Comment: if you have the persons facebook id then simply create a link https://www.facebook.com/facebook_id if you want I can give you full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your first question, you're not going to be able to do this (in a straightforward manner, at least) without implementing the Facebook SDK. Since you don't have the person's Facebook ID, you'll need to prompt them to somehow to provide it to you. The easiest way to do this is to authenticate with Facebook.

You can learn more about the Facebook iOS SDK on Facebook's [Developer Site](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started). There's even a [Getting Started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started) page!

Once you've gotten that set up, you can use the Graph API. From Facebook's [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/graph):

> You can request a user's information by making a me request. And you can do this in two ways:
>
> Using the `FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:completionHandler:` method, like you did in the requesting permissions section, and setting the path to me.
>
> Using the `FBRequestConnection startForMeWithCompletionHandler:` method, which will make a me request directly.

Comment: I see, I guess authentication is needed to prevent people from linking other people's Facebook pages...I'll try hack through the SDK :)